# Is there a svg library for generating line graphs like in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I really like the line graph used in Google Analytics and I think it's done in SVG. Is there a library for generating line graphs like that of Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[d3.js](http://d3js.org/)** is one hell of a powerful library to work with any kinds of graphs.

You can give it a shot and see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, looks like Google let's you have it using the [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a few JS libraries allowing you to build graphs similar to Google Analytics. Try [Morris](http://oesmith.github.com/morris.js/) as a start and I will update the answer when I find the rest in my arsenal